# js, css and images on https not loaded

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, https

**Behavior:**
Every time I access on https many of the css, js and images have not been loaded, I have to refresh like 3 times to sometimes get all the media in the load. On the other hand if I use http every css, js and images load very well.

This behavior started to happened after I renew the site and cert.

**What I've already done:**
I cleared chache and reload on chrome, Safari, ff, android and safari iphone but the behavior continues. I also asked to the host provider to check what happens.

**Steps to reproduce the error:**
On chrome: Open inspect element and go to network, clear cache and reload, many of the css and js not even start to load and the browser does not recognize the MIME type, the not-loaded files are shown as plain text.

I already tried everything on the first page of google

[what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5AAm.jpg)

Comment: Hacked by Shade <3

Comment: Good, please hack it to work :)

Comment: I mean I found this message on your website and I closed my browser immediately to prevent virus.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your CSS and images are accessible over SSL. Try accessing them directly or use Firebug or any similar browser tool to resolve this

Comment: Already try this, if I open the single image in other tab works fine.